# Get Array of structs from custom smart contract deployed on Hedera

Tags: blockchain, solidity, hedera-hashgraph

Suppose I have a solidity contract deployed at address X in Hedera testnet. I want to call a function from the contract deployed at contract X a get function that returns an array of structs...how do I decode that array of structs? (I am using `ContractCallQuery` function from the [Hedera JS SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hashgraph/sdk) library to call the get function) Ref: [Link](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/tutorials/smart-contracts-service/deploy-your-first-smart-contract)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SDKs have support for "simple" data types, for more complex types, I suggest you use existing web3 libraries such as ethers.js, web3.js or abiDecoder.
You can find some examples here, not with structs, but using the above libraries alongside the SDK: https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-smart-contracts-libs-lab